# Other Ajax calls not working after the first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, delegation

just working on a small blogging system and using multiple ajax calls for updating information without page reloads.

However, after one ajax call the others dont work and instead the form goes to the php page itself.

The ajax calls all follow a similar pattern of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.addpost').one("submit",function(e){

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process/addnewpost.php",
        data: $targetForm.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){

        if (response.databaseSuccess) {
           $("#container").load("#container");
        } else {
               $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');
            }
        }
});
});
});
```

On my page, these scripts are loaded like so:

```
<script src="http://buildsanctuary.com/js/addcomment.js"></script>
```

I had the same issue with some button events, but got around the issue using .on() however sometimes this doesnt even work so my solution was to put the even in the ajax success response.

Cant find any answers around about how to bind / delegate a whole script?

Comment: instead of `if else block in success: you can utilize success: and error: `functions. Look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You use `$('.addpost').`**`one`**`("submit",function(e){` to bind the submit event to do your ajax therefore it will ony execute one time, use `on` instead.

```
$('.addpost').on("submit",function(e){
```